# Why doesn't Professor X use one of Magneto's henchmen to take off his helmet and then control Magneto?

Tags: character, x-men-cinematic-universe

In the X-Men Cinematic Universe, Professor X. has the ability to mind control people. The only problem is, he can not mind control the antagonist of the movie, Magneto, because he wears a helmet that protects him from mind control. My question is, why didn't he use his powers to mind control one of Magneto's henchmen and have them take Magneto's helmet off? Then he could easily mind control Magneto, and many problems would be solved.

Comment: Because when controlling Magneto the henchmen can put his helmet back on Erick head. Great for "who's on first" type of skit not so great for dramatic movie.

Comment: Ah, smart. I didn't think of that

Comment: Henchmen with metal armour, metal armour on magneto, not much need for henchmen?

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY Do we actually know that Professor X can only mind-control one person at a time? Hasn’t he controlled multiple people simultaneously at some point in some movie?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet We can definitely freeze lots of people at once, so that's not a problem at all. More than that, controlling Magneto, he could easily restrict henchmen using metal manipulation.

Comment: I think Xavier always care about Erik, whatever he did as Magneto. Xavier still sees his old friend in him

Answer (score 43):

He actually tries something very similar in one of the X-Men movies, where he controls Sabertooth and has him grab Magneto by the throat during a standoff with police, where Magneto has taken all the police weapons and pointed them back at the officers.

Magneto responds by firing one of the floating guns and holding back the bullet from penetrating the police officer's head, until Xavier releases Sabertooth from his control.

Magneto isn't defenceless against his henchmen in any case and is regularly demonstrated to be much more powerful than they are.  Also, if that helmet contains any metal (and it looks like it does), it's not coming off unless he allows it to.

Comment: Yes I know,  that is where I got it from.

Comment: @ZaniXu the very last sentence is the crucial bit i think - magneto's powers extend to his helmet, so even if a henchman tried to yank it off, magneto could probably win a tug-of-war and respond before anything happened.

Comment: Yes, with sabertooh speed and a surprise attack, you can get the helmet off. But magneto reflex is not that bad. You won't be able to take the helmet for a very long time. The time Xavier switch from one controle to an other should be enought. Magneto is able to identify and stop small moving object like bullet. Pretty sure he will notice the helmet moving. It will be "I moved the helmet from one inch before, he moved the Fe in my body from one inch"

Comment: @Knetic you would imagine someone like Sabretooth could literally pull his head off with the helmet still attached to it. But that doesn't make for a nice audience rating.

Comment: @DickieBoy ...well, referencing the last sentence of the answer again, if the head has any metal in it, and it certainly does have Fe in the blood, could his head be pulled off...? (:

Comment: @xDaizu In x-men 2 at Magnetos prison. Magneto is able to lift the security guard because he has too much Iron in his blood(injected by mystique). This is evidence that there needs to be a sufficient concentration of Iron to make able to have his head not move when force is applied. Also if he was able to control it i think it would act the same way(although opposite). The metal would stay in place and the head would be pulled through it. So, yes I think his head could be pulled off.

Comment: @xDaizu The plot of (the start of) one of the movies involved Mystique injecting one of the guards with enough extra iron that Magneto could control him.  So, probably not.

Comment: @DickieBoy It doesn't make sense. With Magneto holding the helmet, sabretooth wouldn't be able to move it in space, not relatively to his head. But of course he could kill him by ripping his throat, it's just not professor's way.

Comment: Regarding the question, originally the helmet did not have any metal in it (we saw that Magneto needed to use the wire to take it from Shaw in First class). But he definetely did put some inside. Firstly, because it would be dumb not to. Secondly, because [this](https://youtu.be/FB9_AsK-uTU?t=55).